# ScriptRunner & Groovy: Tasks to Sub-Tasks

Tags: java, methods, groovy, jira, jira-plugin

I'm working from this blog post: http://codedevstuff.blogspot.com/2015/04/convert-multiple-tasks-to-sub-tasks-in.html

My code is:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchProvider
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.parser.JqlQueryParser
import com.atlassian.jira.web.bean.PagerFilter
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.security.Permissions
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.UpdateIssueRequest;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.UpdateIssueRequest;

def jqlQueryParser = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(JqlQueryParser.class)
def searchProvider = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(SearchProvider.class)
def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()
def user = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getUser()
def parentIdKey = "DIG-11514"
def subTaskIssueTypeId = "5"
//def query = jqlQueryParser.parseQuery("project = AR AND 'Business Requirement Id' ~ '5' AND (" + queryParamsString + ")")
def query = jqlQueryParser.parseQuery("issue in (DIG-16826, DIG-17281, DIG-14493, DIG-13886, DIG-17939, DIG-17071, DIG-15430, DIG-15409, DIG-15409)")
def results = searchProvider.search(query, user, PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter())
results.getIssues().each {documentIssue ->
    //log.debug(documentIssue.key)
    def issue = issueManager.getIssueObject(documentIssue.id)
    changeToSubTaskAndLink(parentIdKey, documentIssue.key, subTaskIssueTypeId)
}
//Method to do all the work
def changeToSubTaskAndLink(parentId, childId, subTaskIssueTypeId)
{
    IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()
    //Get the parent Issue
    def parent = issueManager.getIssueObject(parentId)
    //Get the child Issue
    def child = issueManager.getIssueObject(childId)
    //Change the child to the subtask type
    child.setIssueTypeId(subTaskIssueTypeId)
    //Update the issue
    ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().updateIssue((ApplicationUser)ComponentManager.getInstance().jiraAuthenticationContext?.user, (MutableIssue)child, UpdateIssueRequest.builder().build())
    //Create the subtask link, if this is not done you'll end up with orphans
    ComponentAccessor.getSubTaskManager().createSubTaskIssueLink(parent, child, ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser())
}
```

However, I am always rewarded with: Cannot find matching method com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager#getIssueObject(java.lang.Object). Please check if the if the declared type is right and the method exists.

For example : line 46, column 40. (`def parent`)

[image: can't find matching method]

I am using JIRA v6.4.13

Comment: `getIssueObject` accepts either a Long (issue ID) or a String (issue key). It would seem that you're unintentionally passing in something of a different class. Can you make your local variables and method parameters strongly typed? (eg. use "String" or "Long" instead of "def" and so on.) This will let you see more clearly where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the changeToSubTaskAndLink method, I needed to add a type to the method itself and an object type to those input parameters

```
def void changeToSubTaskAndLink(String parentId, String childId, String subTaskIssueTypeId)
```

ALSO!  note that the internal IDE does not always recognize that some variables may actually be dynamic and will have a non-null value by the time you call getIssueObject so even if it shows an error, just try it out and it might actually work just fine.